# How to add an action in a UML 2 activitydiagram in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, uml, activity-diagram

I have recently started using eclipse and want to use it for UML diagrams. (Before I have been using Dia). My problem is that I simply can't find out how to add an action in an activitydiagram? There are several kinds of actions, but none of them is named simply "Action". Did I miss something? I am using UML2 Extender SDK and UML2 Tools SDK. I am grateful for every hint in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should actually be an Action menu where you can choose the "Opaque Action" which is the most generic. Depentently on your needs there are also other actions (i.e. AcceptEventAction, SendSignalAction, CallBehaviourAction, etc.)